# How can I add usbip modules on Redhat 6 kernel?

Tags: redhat, usb, kernel-modules

I have RHEL 6 with

```
# uname -r
2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
```

I'm trying to build usbip modules on staging driver. Everything is OK. I have all needed *.ko files.
But I cannot add those modules on running kernel.

```
# pwd
/lib/modules/2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
# ls | grep ko
usbip_common_mod.ko
usbip.ko
vhci-hcd.ko

# modprobe usbip
FATAL: Error inserting usbip (/lib/modules/2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64/usbip.ko): Required key not available
# insmod usbip.ko
insmod: error inserting 'usbip.ko': -1 Required key not available
```

How can I add it? Do I need to rebuild whole kernel?

TIA,
giobuon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe RHEL 6 will permit the loading of unsigned modules but not modules signed with an unknown key.

Try removing the signature from the module and loading again:

```
objcopy -R .note.module.sig usbip.ko usbip-new.ko
```